# Public IP works but with DynDNS I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: networking, router, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding

Recently I ran into a strange problem...

I'm using a Raspberry with Raspbian as a public server behind a private router.

I wanted to renew the expiring **sslforfree.com** certificate manually via HTTP. I've already done this many times and prepared a step by step guide for this.

This time it doesn't work. When I try to verify the upload of my verification files via the link: http://MyDynDNSAddress/.well-known/acme-challenge/MyVerificationFile

I get the following error: **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

But when I access the same link with my public IP, it works fine: http://MyPublicIP/.well-known/acme-challenge/MyVerificationFile

I use **no-ip.com** for DynDNS and I have an **Asus** Router

I've already checked the following things:

- Access link via local ip - **works**
- Access link via public ip - **works**
- Check if DynDNS points to correct public ip address - **points to my public ip**
- Deactivate firewall on router - **still refused**
- Reset iptables on Raspberry (accept everything) - **still refused**
- Check port 80 with port checker - **port is open**

What else can I try? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Do you have forwarded traffic on port 80 for public IP to you local server? Check, if you don't have rewrite/redirect enabled (http to https) on your web server (port 80) for location ".well-known/acme-challenge/"

Comment: Why do you use sslforfree.com when all it does is interface with Let’s Encrypt? Let’s Encrypt certificates can be renewed by simple command: `certbot renew  --text --no-self-upgrade > /var/log/letsencrypt_cron.log 2>&1` and restart your server. You could do this with cron and never look back.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the hint, I'll try that and write you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @harrymc I could solve my actual problem of trying to renew the certificates:

> Why do you use sslforfree.com when all it does is interface with Let’s Encrypt? Let’s Encrypt certificates can be renewed by simple command: certbot renew --text --no-self-upgrade > /var/log/letsencrypt_cron.log 2>&1 and restart your server. You could do this with cron and never look back.

I just followed the instructions here: [Let's Encrypt - Getting started](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/)

But my problem mentioned in the description of course wasn't solved by that. I have no need in solving it anymore. So I'll mark this question as answered.

**Thank you** very much for your help!